# Overlapping divs on Mobile device in Nationbuilder site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, overlapping

I am working on customizing a Nationbuilder theme which is built using Bootstrap CSS and Liquid. I've got everything working on all platforms except for the signup box on the header when viewed on a mobile phone is overlapping the logo. Because it is Nationbuilder, I can't modify all the containers. 
This is the code in the master template file:

```
<body class="aware-theme v2-theme {{ page.page_class_name }} page-{{ request.template | replace: '_', '-' }} js">

{% if site.has_header_image? and page.features_count == 0 %}
<div class="container header-image-container"> 
 <img src="{{ site.header_image_url_1026 }}" class="header-image img-responsive" border="0" />
</div>
{% endif %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"><br clear="all">{% subpage "join" with "homepage_signup" %}</div> </div>
{% include "nav" %}

{% if page.features_count > 0 %}
  <div class="container">
   {% include "features" %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Where it says "subpage join" is where I call in the content for the sign up box. I've tried moving this code higher in the HTML but then it disappears.

The content is resizing for mobile which is good but the positioning is off because the box overlaps the logo.

Here is the CSS for the signup box:

```
.headerbox {
position: absolute;
z-index:99999;
margin: 0px 0px 100x 0px;
top:20px;
border: solid 1px $theme-color-1;
padding: 5px;
font: $headline-font;
font-size: .8em;
text-align:center;
}
```

and this is the CSS for the logo:

```
.site-logo {
padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top:-30px;
}
.navbar {
background: $header-color;
margin-bottom: 0px;
max-height: 190px
}
```

Comment: could it be the margin-top: -30px on your .navbar-brand class?  You could remove or change that with a media query

Comment: no it's not that because I didn't have that there before and it still was an issue. i'm not sure on media queries.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle?  Without the html it's hard to see exactly what the problem is

Comment: Ok, brand new to this but here: https://jsfiddle.net/creativeliza/xkz75q0s/